# Ansible: git clone fails with "fatal: Out of memory, realloc failed"

Tags: windows, git, ansible, git-lfs

I'm using Ansible with a Windows host (VM).
I'm trying to `git clone` a large content (actually using `git lfs`). It's around 15Go in total

I'm using `git for windows` (https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.37.2.windows.2).

I have the following Ansible task:

```
- name: Clone repository
  ansible.windows.win_command: >
    <path/to/git.exe> clone <git-repo>
```

The problem is that it always fails with the error:

`fatal: Out of memory, realloc failed`

I tried to increase the windows VM memory, or to play with `git config` settings, as explained in several posts, for example:

- [remote: fatal: Out of memory, realloc failed on git push with post-receive hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39563566/remote-fatal-out-of-memory-realloc-failed-on-git-push-with-post-receive-hook)
- [git out of memory on checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360328/git-out-of-memory-on-checkout)
- https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Message-erro-quot-fatal-Out-of-memory-realloc-failed-quot/qaq-p/894048

But none of these solutions work for me. It always failed at the same points:

```
"Filtering content:  48% (440/902), 2.11 GiB | 6.70 MiB/s",
"fatal: Out of memory, realloc failed",
"Error downloading object: xxxxxxx: Smudge error: Error reading from media file: write /dev/stdout: The pipe is being closed.: write /dev/stdout: The pipe is being closed.",
"",
"Errors logged to 'xxxx.log'.",
"Use `git lfs logs last` to view the log.",
"warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.",
"You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'",
"and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'"
```

The weird things is that this error only happen using Ansible. If I connect to the VM and manually run exactly the same `git clone` command, everything goes well.

Do you have any idea to help me? Thanks

Comment: You might try splitting this into two steps: (1) clone without LFS installed, so that you get "pointer files" instead of real ones (use `--no-checkout` to skip the useless checkout). (2) install LFS and poke it into downloading the real files. It's possible that using `--no-checkout` alone first might avoid the problem, but doing it in two steps means that Git can run without the Git-LFS wrappers hogging memory, and then Git-LFS can run with a less-memory-intensive Git operation.

Comment: This is a pure git checkout problem. Removing ansible tag.

Comment: I understand the problem comes from `git checkout`. However, it only happens when I use Ansible. I don't have this issue when I run directly on the host

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same behaviour in a similar situation. I was trying to do a reference clone for a repository that's originally over 100GB and also contains LFS files. The out of memory was only seen when trying to execute the clone via Ansible's `win_shell`.

What worked for me was using the Ansible `win_shell` module and increasing the `MaxMemoryPerShellMB` to a large enough value. I figured out the value by doubling the memory until it was larger than the default value but smaller or equal to the actual memory limits of my machine.

Including a snippet of what tasks you'll need to resolve this problem successfully:

```
---
- name: Increase MaxMemoryPerShellMB
  win_shell: 'Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB <value>'

- name: Clone the repository
  win_shell: '<git clone command>'
  args:
    executable: cmd
```

Additionally, if it's possible for your usecase, I'd recommend skipping the clone of LFS files and fetching the files that you need afterwards. Refer to the `git config` commands in '[How to clone/pull a git repository, ignoring LFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42021818/7323787)'. It's subtle but the answer seems to indicate that `GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE` variable is obsolete for Windows. I'm still trying to find a proper piece of documentation for this.

I hope this helps you!